# onorientationchange not "detecting" portrait

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to determine why `onorientationchange` isn't working in my code, so I made this mini test file.

For some reason and logic which I don't understand, it's not detecting the "portrait" orientation of the screen.

Any and all help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

```js
var maxW = window.screen.availWidth;
var maxH = window.screen.availHeight;

window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {
  if (maxW < maxH){
    document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    document.getElementById("inner").innerHTML = "P";
  }else{
    document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    document.getElementById("inner").innerHTML = "L";
  } 
});
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#box{
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}

#inner{
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: bold;
  top: 34%;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>  
  <body>
    <div id="box">
      <div id="inner">
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should put the definitions of `maxW` and `maxH` inside the listener. Currently they're read only once, when the page was just loaded.

Comment: that solved it. thanks, make this an anwser and I'll accept.